# The magic number in GZip header is not correct decompression give me error

Tags: c#, .net, compression

This decompress method is give me a error in which this line `(numRead = Decompress.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0` give me error like The magic number in `GZip` header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a `GZip` stream.

I posted my code here with

```
public bool Decompress(string zipPathAndFile, string outputFolder, string password, bool deleteZipFile)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(zipPathAndFile);
    try
    {
        // Get the stream of the source file.
        using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            // Get original file extension, for example "doc" from report.doc.gz.
            string curFile = fi.Name;
            string origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length - fi.Extension.Length);

            //Create the decompressed file.
            using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(outputFolder.TrimEnd('\\') + '\\' + origName))
            {
                using (GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    //Copy the decompression stream into the output file.
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int numRead;
                    while ((numRead = Decompress.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        outFile.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (System.Exception exc)
    {
        ExceptionManagerBll.ErrHandler(exc, "ERR", 3, new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true)).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name, new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true)).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, "Error is Occured", true, false, "", "");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: while ((numRead = Decompress.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) give me a error

Comment: Something went wrong with the formatting of the code in your question. Please edit the question, and move the information from your comment there as well.

Comment: @RolandWeber now you can see the code

Comment: i am using .net frame work 4

Comment: "Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream." - have you double checked that, i.e. that you are actually passing a GZIP compressed file?

Comment: @christian-k my file extension is .gz

Comment: @ketan1300 A file extension doesn't mean that the _content_ of the file is actually of that type. I can name a ".txt" file (containing plain ascii textcontent) into ".gz", but that doesn't make it a GZIP-compressed file. If unsure, use a tool (like 7zip) and try to open the file and see what it tells you. To see what makes up the GZIP file format [see this](http://zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html).